# How to using layers of another basemap in a Mapbox basemap

Tags: mapbox, bing-maps, mapbox-gl-js, yandex-maps

I am using a Mapbox map pad on my website. I would also like to add the footers of maps such as bing-maps or yandex-maps to my mapbox layers to give the user more options. So I want to use layers of other maps while continuing to use mapbox is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Bing Maps can be added as a raster tile layer. Details on how to directly access Bing Maps tiles is documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/rest-services/directly-accessing-the-bing-maps-tiles

If you want vector tiles from Microsoft, there is also Azure Maps (they have traffic data tiles available in vector and raster format too):

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/maps/render-v2/get-map-tile
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/maps/traffic/get-traffic-flow-tile
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/maps/traffic/get-traffic-incident-tile
- https://samples.azuremaps.com/?search=vector%2520tile

Note that the Azure Maps Web SDK, uses MapLibre under the hood (a fork of Mapbox) and wraps it with an easier to use developer API. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-maps/how-to-use-map-control